# jdbc: " Invalid object name '[table name]'."

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

So for the past few hours i've been trying to set up a database and to then use the database as DataSource in a Java Servlet (I'm using Netbeans). For some reason I keep getting the error "Invalid object name 'Accounts" when I try to execute the statement "insert into Accounts(Email, Hash, Salt) values(xyz, xyz, xyz). I have no clue why this keeps happening, because I definitely have the table in my database.

I use SQL Server 2016.

My context.xml file is set up as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/opdracht2">
  <Resource auth="Container" 
            driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
            logAbandoned="true" 
            maxActive="8"
            maxIdle="4"
            name="jdbc/H4O"
            password="secret" 
            removeAbandoned="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-PS13CKQ;integratedSecurity=true"
            username="DESKTOP-PS13CKQ\MemeMeister"/>
</Context>
```

When I run the following code to see what tables there are:

```
Connection connection;
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
ResultSet rs2 = md.getSchemas();
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("rs.getString(3));
}
System.out.println("------Schemas-----");
while (rs2.next()) {
    System.out.println(
    rs2.getString("TABLE_SCHEM") 
    + ", "+rs2.getString("TABLE_CATALOG"));
}
```

I get the following output:

```
MSreplication_options
spt_fallback_db
spt_fallback_dev
spt_fallback_usg
spt_monitor
trace_xe_action_map
trace_xe_event_map
spt_values
CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
COLUMN_DOMAIN_USAGE
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
COLUMNS
CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE
DOMAIN_CONSTRAINTS
DOMAINS
KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
PARAMETERS
REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
ROUTINE_COLUMNS
ROUTINES
SCHEMATA
SEQUENCES
TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
TABLE_PRIVILEGES
TABLES
VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE
VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
VIEWS
all_columns
all_objects
all_parameters
all_sql_modules
all_views
allocation_units
assemblies
assembly_files
assembly_modules
assembly_references
assembly_types
asymmetric_keys
availability_databases_cluster
availability_group_listener_ip_addresses
availability_group_listeners
availability_groups
availability_groups_cluster
availability_read_only_routing_lists
availability_replicas
backup_devices
certificates
change_tracking_databases
change_tracking_tables
check_constraints
column_encryption_key_values
column_encryption_keys
column_master_keys
column_store_dictionaries
column_store_row_groups
column_store_segments
column_type_usages
column_xml_schema_collection_usages
columns
computed_columns
configurations
conversation_endpoints
conversation_groups
conversation_priorities
credentials
crypt_properties
cryptographic_providers
data_spaces
database_audit_specification_details
database_audit_specifications
database_credentials
database_files
database_filestream_options
database_mirroring
database_mirroring_endpoints
database_mirroring_witnesses
database_permissions
database_principals
database_query_store_options
database_recovery_status
database_role_members
database_scoped_configurations
database_scoped_credentials
databases
default_constraints
destination_data_spaces
dm_audit_actions
dm_audit_class_type_map
dm_broker_activated_tasks
dm_broker_connections
dm_broker_forwarded_messages
dm_broker_queue_monitors
dm_cdc_errors
dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions
dm_clr_appdomains
dm_clr_loaded_assemblies
dm_clr_properties
dm_clr_tasks
dm_column_store_object_pool
dm_cryptographic_provider_properties
dm_database_encryption_keys
dm_db_column_store_row_group_operational_stats
dm_db_column_store_row_group_physical_stats
dm_db_file_space_usage
dm_db_fts_index_physical_stats
dm_db_index_usage_stats
dm_db_log_space_usage
dm_db_mirroring_auto_page_repair
dm_db_mirroring_connections
dm_db_mirroring_past_actions
dm_db_missing_index_details
dm_db_missing_index_group_stats
dm_db_missing_index_groups
dm_db_partition_stats
dm_db_persisted_sku_features
dm_db_rda_migration_status
dm_db_rda_schema_update_status
dm_db_script_level
dm_db_session_space_usage
dm_db_task_space_usage
dm_db_uncontained_entities
dm_db_xtp_checkpoint_files
dm_db_xtp_checkpoint_stats
dm_db_xtp_gc_cycle_stats
dm_db_xtp_hash_index_stats
dm_db_xtp_index_stats
dm_db_xtp_memory_consumers
dm_db_xtp_nonclustered_index_stats
dm_db_xtp_object_stats
dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats
dm_db_xtp_transactions
dm_exec_background_job_queue
dm_exec_background_job_queue_stats
dm_exec_cached_plans
dm_exec_compute_node_errors
dm_exec_compute_node_status
dm_exec_compute_nodes
dm_exec_connections
dm_exec_distributed_request_steps
dm_exec_distributed_requests
dm_exec_distributed_sql_requests
dm_exec_dms_services
dm_exec_dms_workers
dm_exec_external_operations
dm_exec_external_work
dm_exec_function_stats
dm_exec_procedure_stats
dm_exec_query_memory_grants
dm_exec_query_optimizer_info
dm_exec_query_optimizer_memory_gateways
dm_exec_query_parallel_workers
dm_exec_query_profiles
dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores
dm_exec_query_stats
dm_exec_query_transformation_stats
dm_exec_requests
dm_exec_session_wait_stats
dm_exec_sessions
dm_exec_trigger_stats
dm_exec_valid_use_hints
dm_external_script_execution_stats
dm_external_script_requests
dm_filestream_file_io_handles
dm_filestream_file_io_requests
dm_filestream_non_transacted_handles
dm_fts_active_catalogs
dm_fts_fdhosts
dm_fts_index_population
dm_fts_memory_buffers
dm_fts_memory_pools
dm_fts_outstanding_batches
dm_fts_population_ranges
dm_fts_semantic_similarity_population
dm_hadr_auto_page_repair
dm_hadr_automatic_seeding
dm_hadr_availability_group_states
dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_nodes
dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states
dm_hadr_availability_replica_states
dm_hadr_cluster
dm_hadr_cluster_members
dm_hadr_cluster_networks
dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states
dm_hadr_database_replica_states
dm_hadr_instance_node_map
dm_hadr_name_id_map
dm_hadr_physical_seeding_stats
dm_io_backup_tapes
dm_io_cluster_shared_drives
dm_io_cluster_valid_path_names
dm_io_pending_io_requests
dm_logpool_hashentries
dm_logpool_stats
dm_os_buffer_descriptors
dm_os_buffer_pool_extension_configuration
dm_os_child_instances
dm_os_cluster_nodes
dm_os_cluster_properties
dm_os_dispatcher_pools
dm_os_dispatchers
dm_os_hosts
dm_os_latch_stats
dm_os_loaded_modules
dm_os_memory_allocations
dm_os_memory_broker_clerks
dm_os_memory_brokers
dm_os_memory_cache_clock_hands
dm_os_memory_cache_counters
dm_os_memory_cache_entries
dm_os_memory_cache_hash_tables
dm_os_memory_clerks
dm_os_memory_node_access_stats
dm_os_memory_nodes
dm_os_memory_objects
dm_os_memory_pools
dm_os_nodes
dm_os_performance_counters
dm_os_process_memory
dm_os_ring_buffers
dm_os_schedulers
dm_os_server_diagnostics_log_configurations
dm_os_spinlock_stats
dm_os_stacks
dm_os_sublatches
dm_os_sys_info
dm_os_sys_memory
dm_os_tasks
dm_os_threads
dm_os_virtual_address_dump
dm_os_wait_stats
dm_os_waiting_tasks
dm_os_windows_info
dm_os_worker_local_storage
dm_os_workers
dm_qn_subscriptions
dm_repl_articles
dm_repl_schemas
dm_repl_tranhash
dm_repl_traninfo
dm_resource_governor_configuration
dm_resource_governor_external_resource_pool_affinity
dm_resource_governor_external_resource_pools
dm_resource_governor_resource_pool_affinity
dm_resource_governor_resource_pool_volumes
dm_resource_governor_resource_pools
dm_resource_governor_workload_groups
dm_server_audit_status
dm_server_memory_dumps
dm_server_registry
dm_server_services
dm_tcp_listener_states
dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions
dm_tran_active_transactions
dm_tran_commit_table
dm_tran_current_snapshot
dm_tran_current_transaction
dm_tran_database_transactions
dm_tran_global_recovery_transactions
dm_tran_global_transactions
dm_tran_global_transactions_enlistments
dm_tran_global_transactions_log
dm_tran_locks
dm_tran_session_transactions
dm_tran_top_version_generators
dm_tran_transactions_snapshot
dm_tran_version_store
dm_xe_map_values
dm_xe_object_columns
dm_xe_objects
dm_xe_packages
dm_xe_session_event_actions
dm_xe_session_events
dm_xe_session_object_columns
dm_xe_session_targets
dm_xe_sessions
dm_xtp_gc_queue_stats
dm_xtp_gc_stats
dm_xtp_system_memory_consumers
dm_xtp_threads
dm_xtp_transaction_recent_rows
dm_xtp_transaction_stats
endpoint_webmethods
endpoints
event_notification_event_types
event_notifications
events
extended_procedures
extended_properties
external_data_sources
external_file_formats
external_tables
filegroups
filetable_system_defined_objects
filetables
foreign_key_columns
foreign_keys
fulltext_catalogs
fulltext_document_types
fulltext_index_catalog_usages
fulltext_index_columns
fulltext_index_fragments
fulltext_indexes
fulltext_languages
fulltext_semantic_language_statistics_database
fulltext_semantic_languages
fulltext_stoplists
fulltext_stopwords
fulltext_system_stopwords
function_order_columns
hash_indexes
http_endpoints
identity_columns
index_columns
indexes
internal_partitions
internal_tables
key_constraints
key_encryptions
linked_logins
login_token
masked_columns
master_files
master_key_passwords
memory_optimized_tables_internal_attributes
message_type_xml_schema_collection_usages
messages
module_assembly_usages
numbered_procedure_parameters
numbered_procedures
objects
openkeys
parameter_type_usages
parameter_xml_schema_collection_usages
parameters
partition_functions
partition_parameters
partition_range_values
partition_schemes
partitions
periods
plan_guides
procedures
query_context_settings
query_store_plan
query_store_query
query_store_query_text
query_store_runtime_stats
query_store_runtime_stats_interval
registered_search_properties
registered_search_property_lists
remote_data_archive_databases
remote_data_archive_tables
remote_logins
remote_service_bindings
resource_governor_configuration
resource_governor_external_resource_pool_affinity
resource_governor_external_resource_pools
resource_governor_resource_pool_affinity
resource_governor_resource_pools
resource_governor_workload_groups
routes
schemas
securable_classes
security_policies
security_predicates
selective_xml_index_namespaces
selective_xml_index_paths
sequences
server_assembly_modules
server_audit_specification_details
server_audit_specifications
server_audits
server_event_notifications
server_event_session_actions
server_event_session_events
server_event_session_fields
server_event_session_targets
server_event_sessions
server_events
server_file_audits
server_permissions
server_principal_credentials
server_principals
server_role_members
server_sql_modules
server_trigger_events
server_triggers
servers
service_broker_endpoints
service_contract_message_usages
service_contract_usages
service_contracts
service_message_types
service_queue_usages
service_queues
services
soap_endpoints
spatial_index_tessellations
spatial_indexes
spatial_reference_systems
sql_dependencies
sql_expression_dependencies
sql_logins
sql_modules
stats
stats_columns
symmetric_keys
synonyms
sysaltfiles
syscacheobjects
syscharsets
syscolumns
syscomments
sysconfigures
sysconstraints
syscurconfigs
syscursorcolumns
syscursorrefs
syscursors
syscursortables
sysdatabases
sysdepends
sysdevices
sysfilegroups
sysfiles
sysforeignkeys
sysfulltextcatalogs
sysindexes
sysindexkeys
syslanguages
syslockinfo
syslogins
sysmembers
sysmessages
sysobjects
sysoledbusers
sysopentapes
sysperfinfo
syspermissions
sysprocesses
sysprotects
sysreferences
sysremotelogins
sysservers
system_columns
system_components_surface_area_configuration
system_internals_allocation_units
system_internals_partition_columns
system_internals_partitions
system_objects
system_parameters
system_sql_modules
system_views
systypes
sysusers
table_types
tables
tcp_endpoints
time_zone_info
trace_categories
trace_columns
trace_event_bindings
trace_events
trace_subclass_values
traces
transmission_queue
trigger_event_types
trigger_events
triggers
type_assembly_usages
types
user_token
via_endpoints
views
xml_indexes
xml_schema_attributes
xml_schema_collections
xml_schema_component_placements
xml_schema_components
xml_schema_elements
xml_schema_facets
xml_schema_model_groups
xml_schema_namespaces
xml_schema_types
xml_schema_wildcard_namespaces
xml_schema_wildcards
-----Schemas-----
db_accessadmin, null
db_backupoperator, null
db_datareader, null
db_datawriter, null
db_ddladmin, null
db_denydatareader, null
db_denydatawriter, null
db_owner, null
db_securityadmin, null
dbo, null
guest, null
INFORMATION_SCHEMA, null
sys, null
```

The Schema dbo is in there, but none of my tables seem to be in the list. Here are a few SSMS screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If anyone can help me solve the problems, it would be great!

**--edit--**
In SQL server configuration manager I have the following error;
[image]

Comment: It just a tip, but you may have to prefix the table name with the database name. eg: H40.Accounts

Comment: @BalázsNemes Thanks for the tip! However, this gives the same error but rather than object 'Accounts' it now says 'H4O.Accounts'.

Comment: It looks like Accounts is under the dbo schema.  Are you able to query H40.dbo.Accounts?

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with java, but it seems that you connected to the user's default database, which in SQL Server is `master`. So, your context is not properly configured. I see that database name is in `name` attribute, which, I think, stores the name of the connection. Try adding it in `url` attribute as:
`url="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-PS13CKQ/H40;integratedSecurity=true"`.
It's just a guess, based on [this link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-a-sql-server-datasource-in-apache-tomcat-218269283.html)(step 3)

**EDIT**

As @Mark Rotteveel said in the comments, it should be `jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-PS13CKQ;databaseName=H40;integrated‌​Security=true`. More details on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply! This leaves me with the following error:  "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host DESKTOP-PS13CKQ/H4O, port 1433 has failed. Error: "DESKTOP-PS13CKQ/H4O. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)". In SQL Server Configuration Manager I have enabled TCP/IP however.

Comment: It should be `jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-PS13CKQ;databaseName=H40;integratedSecurity=true`, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it.... For some reason the URL to the DB was wrong. It originally was "url="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-PS13CKQ;integratedSecurity=true"", and now I added ";databaseName=H4O" to the end of that URL. This seems to solve everything. Not quite sure how that all works, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but in my case it was because of an extra column I had in my entity which was not mapped to the table in database.
i had `@Version` in my entity and not table, which after removing solved the issue